# Show PDF file in GWT app

Tags: java, gwt, servlets

I have a PDF file stored in server and I want to display it on the client side. How can I make the pdf displayed in the required place?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a frame widget with a reference to your PDF file. The Frame widget in GWT will render an HTML iFrame in your browser.

```
public class FrameExample implements EntryPoint {

  public void onModuleLoad() {
    // Make a new frame, and point it at Google.
    Frame frame = new Frame("http://www.mydomain.com/path to my pdf");

    // Add it to the root panel. or anywhere you want
    RootPanel.get().add(frame);
  }
}
```

Comment: You should mention that the GWT class Frame actually represents an IFRAME, not an HTML FRAME (just to avoid any anti-frame reflexes that people might have ;-))

Comment: i am new to GWT and currently i am developing under Dev mode, so could u tell me how to get the path to the pdf file?

Comment: And is there any way I can download the pdf file from a servlet and show it inside the Frame? Thank you.

Comment: @John You can have a look at http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javatips/jw-javatip94.html for downloading the pdf file.

Comment: @Grrrrr Hi, I tried your method, but the pdf file was opened by PDF reader instead of displaying inside the frame.

Answer (score 0):

I have used following. Its working fine. May be its usefull for you.

GWT Client side:

```
HTML pdf = new HTML("<embed src='http://www.mydomain.com/path to my pdf' width='100%' height='500px'></embed>");
PDFPannel.add(pdf);
```